# Indicar arquivo em uma string

Tags: c#, .net, string, xml, variáveis

Estou desenvolvendo um site em .NET Core Razor Pages. Como eu posso fazer com que eu indique um arquivo para uma variável? Por exemplo:

```
var xml = (~/MenuXML/menu.xml);
```

**OBS:** Preciso que seja em string, os dados do arquivo.

**Motivo:** Estou tentando transformá-lo em JSON. O código que estou usando está a seguir:

```
var xml = (~/MenuXML/menu.xml);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

HttpContext.Session.SetString("xmltojson", json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, sei que esta pergunta tem pouco tempo, mas eu pesquisei um pouco mais e consegui uma forma de fazer isso, então caso alguém precise, vou deixar aqui nas respostas.

```
var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\ArquivoXML\arquivo.Xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
HttpContext.Session.SetString("xmltojson", json);
```